# Automatically call numbers and play audio message

Tags: android, audio, asterisk, phone-call, voice

Basically there is a list of customer mobile numbers I like to call and play a recorded audio message. SMS is not an option. I was shocked to see that android does not support this and there is not much help available online regarding this. Any clues of how this would be accomplished? Will I need any specific hardware and/or software for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://vicidial.org

Unfortanly you need voip account and linux server for that

Comment: Thanks but using a VOIP account is not acceptable for me. I want to use the local GSM SIMs to make the calls. I thought there would be some SIM Modem which would allow such functionality using Asterisk or something else. I have seen marketing people doing this but I wonder what technologies they are using.

Comment: You can't. Android security will not allow you do that. You can use asterisk with gsm gate(google sip gsm gate).

Comment: Asterisk will work with specific versions of Huawei voice capable 3G/HSDPA modems: https://github.com/bg111/asterisk-chan-dongle . But it's not easy and definitely hard to achieve.